# ios 7, where do i store AES key? do i need to encrypt that as well?

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography

am planning to use symmetric key encryption between ios 7 app and my server backend.

1. i generated an AES key on my linux machine. i intend to use that in my app. is this the right way to generate key?

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k  -P -md md5

2. can i leave that key in my ios 7 app hardcoded as say

```
#define encKey "asdfasdfasdfaadfa"
```

or do i need other mechanism to encrypt above key? any other ways to protect this?

appreciate any help.

Comment: The key can be extracted from your program. You could encrypt that key using another key, but that key can be extracted too. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/why-can-we-still-crack-snapchat-photos-in-12-lines-of-ruby.

Comment: thanks for reply. symmetric key encryption may not be right choice here. am inclining towards TLS or SSL connection between ios device and my server. am linking my app with libSKPSMTP, which uses TLS to talk to gmail servers. i can write my own server but I never played with TLS or SSL api before.

Comment: can i instead package the symmetric key in file. when the app is launched first, it could read this key from file, save in key-store (or something equivalent that is provided for all apps and is secure) and then delete that file. is that possible? thanks

Comment: Of course it's possible. But anyone could read that file, so it's moot. You're trying to solve the "DRM problem" which does not have a solution.